# single Queue and multiple Queue using same program not work

Tags: c, data-structures, crash, queue

here is two c program to implement queue data structure in simple form

- *the first:*

  define one queue and it's work perfectly
- the second:

  define multiple queues and it's crash at execution

functions are the same in both programs except the `main()` were the implementation
are different little bit.

So the question here: why the second code not working?

*** here is the codes ***

*code 1:*

```
/*
 Single queue  -- this work perfectly
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#define Q_MAX_SIZE 255

struct queue {
    int* pointer;
    int* currentValue;
    int max, count, theQueue[Q_MAX_SIZE];
};

//prototyps
void initQueue(struct queue*);
unsigned short pushQueue(struct queue*, int);
int* popQueue(struct queue*);

int main(void) {
    int j;
    struct queue q;

    initQueue(&q);

    for (j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        pushQueue(&q, j);

    int* inputobj = popQueue(&q);
    while (inputobj != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d  ", *inputobj);
        inputobj = popQueue(&q);
    }

    printf("\n\ndone..Queue is empty\n");

    return 0;
}

//@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

void initQueue(struct queue *Q)
{
    Q->pointer = Q->theQueue;
    Q->max = Q_MAX_SIZE;
    Q->count = 0;
}

unsigned short pushQueue(struct queue *Q, int input) {
    if (Q->count < Q->max)
    {
       *Q->pointer = input;
        Q->pointer++;
        Q->count++;
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

//@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

int* popQueue(struct queue *Q) {
    int i;
    if (Q->count > 0)
    {

       *Q->currentValue = *Q->theQueue;
        Q->pointer--;
        Q->count--;

        for (i = 0; i < Q->count; i++)
        {
            int* currentPtr = Q->theQueue + i;
            int* nextPtr = currentPtr + 1;
            *currentPtr = *nextPtr;
        }

        return Q->currentValue;
    }
    else
        NULL;
}
```

*code 2:*

```
/*
 Multiple queues  -- this not work and crash at execution
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#define Q_MAX_SIZE 255

struct queue {
    int* pointer;
    int* currentValue;
    int max, count, theQueue[Q_MAX_SIZE];
};

//prototyps
void initQueue(struct queue*);
unsigned short pushQueue(struct queue*, int);
int* popQueue(struct queue*);

int main(void) {
        int i, j;
    struct queue obj[5];

    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        initQueue(&obj[i]);

        for(j = 0; j<3; j++)
        {
            pushQueue(&obj[i], j);
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf("Queue[%d]:\n", i);
        int* inputobj;
        inputobj = popQueue(&obj[i]);

        while(inputobj != NULL)
        {
            printf("Queue[No.%d] = %d\n", i, *inputobj);
            inputobj = popQueue(&obj[i]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}

//@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

void initQueue(struct queue *Q)
{
    Q->pointer = Q->theQueue;
    Q->max = Q_MAX_SIZE;
    Q->count = 0;
}

unsigned short pushQueue(struct queue *Q, int input) {
    if (Q->count < Q->max)
    {
       *Q->pointer = input;
        Q->pointer++;
        Q->count++;
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

//@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

int* popQueue(struct queue *Q) {
    int i;
    if (Q->count > 0)
    {

       *Q->currentValue = *Q->theQueue;
        Q->pointer--;
        Q->count--;

        for (i = 0; i < Q->count; i++)
        {
            int* currentPtr = Q->theQueue + i;
            int* nextPtr = currentPtr + 1;
            *currentPtr = *nextPtr;
        }

        return Q->currentValue;
    }
    else
        NULL;
}
```

**Update:** the problem was in `initQueue()` and it's solved by allocating memory
 for `Q->currentValue` here is the function after editing:

```
void initQueue(struct queue *Q)
{
    Q->currentValue = malloc(sizeof(int));
    Q->pointer = Q->theQueue;
    Q->max = Q_MAX_SIZE;
    Q->count = 0;
}
```

Comment: learn how to use debbuger, to see what's going on

Comment: My guess is that you should be accessing like this:  initQueue(&(obj[i]));

Comment: @Jim i did what you say but it is not work

Comment: Where does it crash?  Put print statements after each major step.  Does it init? push?  Where does it crash?

Comment: hi @Jim here is the problem start at line 38[http://codepad.org/iFyt5iBy ] and here is the test output [http://codepad.org/0jx2EfnW ] finally here is the right code to make it work [http://codepad.org/BYouZvNP ] but i ask the question here to know why it is not work as in the code in the question ... the reason .. thanks again :)

Comment: In any case, you shouldn't have just NULL.  You should return NULL.

Comment: First one doe NOT work.

Comment: @Jim for the `NULL` you are right i forget the `return` keyword ..thank you for all your effort

Comment: @Abdulrhman.Z: what is pointer supposed to point to? and currentValue? what are their invariants (useful properties that should always hold)?

Comment: another deficiency of your solution is that removing an element takes O(n) in stead of the common O(1)

Comment: Hi @jev i am still in the beginning of learning C and queue code implemented here was an example in data structure lesson .. thanks for the hint and i am not getting involve in DS and algorithms yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As both answers already stated, the problem is that `Q->current_value` has never been assigned a value to and so it points to an undefined address and every dereferencing like `*Q->currentValue = ..` is undefined behaviour. The fact that code 1 seemingly works doesn't prove anything else because due to the nature of UB no behaviour is guaranteed, your program may or may not crash (or your dog may explode, dragons fly out of your nose ... :-) )

Of course there are multiple solutions that all mean something different:

1. if `currentValue` should just hold a copy of a certain value, it could be `int currentValue` instead of `int *...` and the assignnment would be

   Q->currentValue = *Q->theQueue;

   and the return statement would be `return &Q->currentValue`. In that case you would return a pointer to the **original** value of `theQueue[0]`
2. if you want to point to the location in `theQueue`, Jim's anser tells the correct way:

   Q->currentValue = Q->theQueue;

   In that case you yould return a pointer to the **new** value of `theQueue[0]` (which may be what you don't want)
3. you could allocate memory to `Q->currentValue` my `malloc( sizeof (int) );` and then leave the assignment as it is. In that case you would return a pointer to the **original** value of `theQueue[0]` like in (1)

Comment: @lngo Leonhardt thank you i understand point 1 & 2 but for the point 3 i get confuse little bit about where to put `malloc( sizeof (int) );` in `initQueue()` or in `popQueue()` ? ...thanks again :)

Comment: Q->currentValue = malloc(sizeof(int));  Put this in the InitQueue() routine.

Comment: @Jim it's work now when i allocate memory for the `Q->currentValue` in the `code2` in `initQueue` ... thanks thanks Mr.Jim

Comment: @Jim @Ingo-leonhardt BTW to be honest with you i am still learning `C language` fundamentals, so i am not get to **Dynamic Memory Allocation** yet but i am in progress.. i know my question take more than it should because of the zero knowledge that i have about **DMA**.. sorry guys ;( and thank you all for all the answers and hits that you give it to me

Comment: Remember for bigger programs when you want to discard something that has mallocs in it, you should free the malloced memory:  free(Q->current_value)  so that you don't leak out memory.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually are really subtle problem, I think.  The problem (I THINK) is this line in popqueue():

```
*Q->currentValue = *Q->theQueue;
```

I double-checked and your initial code (no array) also seg faults.  It does not work as you have said.  You should have written:

```
Q->currentValue = Q->theQueue;
```

C can be a bit understanding with pointers and assign things appropriately, but when you added another level (arrays) I think the assignment was forced into something that didn't work.  That's my take on it.  I think I will put up a bounty so you can get a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, I would not try to put code like this one in production. Things can be done more simple, clear, performant and less error prone.

I've "fixed" your program by changing things in as little as possible places. It must be clear that this doesn't make things more elegant. Only rethinking and rewriting would make things more elegant.

The error you have (both in the first and the second program) is the routine popQueue.

1. You return nothing in the else clause. You should "return NULL". This is at least sloppy programming.
2. The routines return 1 2 3 4 5 5 and 1 2 2 for a queue. This is because Q->CurrentValue points to the first place in the theQueue array, and you shift up all values. This means that CurrentValue defacto points to the next value.

The solution (again: it's not elegant, nor would I put it in production, but it is with minimal change to the original) to your problem is:

1. Change in the struct (to hold the real CurrentValue)

   ```
   struct queue
   {
     int* pointer;
     int currentValue;
     int max, count, theQueue[Q_MAX_SIZE];
   };
   ```
2. Change the routine popQueue

   ```
   int* popQueue(struct queue *Q) {
       int i;
       if (Q->count > 0)
       {

           Q->currentValue = *Q->theQueue;
           Q->pointer--;
           Q->count--;

           for (i = 0; i < Q->count; i++)
           {
               int* currentPtr = Q->theQueue + i;
               int* nextPtr = currentPtr + 1;
               *currentPtr = *nextPtr;
           }

           return &(Q->currentValue);
       }
       else
           return NULL;
   }
   ```

Kind regards,
PB

Comment: thanks for the clarification, you don't add any thing new to what the guys **Jim** and **Ingo-leonhardt** says.. anyway i get were the problem is thank you all guys

Answer (score 0):

The location Q->currentValue cannot be accessed, that is the problem. It is not allocated.

The solution is to allocate the right portion of memory in the init routine:

```
Q = malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
```

perhaps also initializing the value of all your variables after that.

Comment: Hi @MatteoD i did what you say but it did not work here is initQueue after editing [http://codepad.org/aISEmUTk]

Comment: I could not open the link.

Comment: This isn't the problem.

Comment: But it's close.  He just needs to allocate for the current pointer within Q.  Q->current_pointer = malloc(sizeof(int));